# How can I prevent Xcode from repeatedly copying the Swift standard libraries into my app?

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode always runs a build phase called "Copy Swift standard libraries", even when it has already copied them and it's doing an incremental build. How can I prevent this from happening when it's not necessary?